# Difference Between setDefaultSchemaName() and setLiquibaseSchemaName() in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Difference Between setDefaultSchemaName() and setLiquibaseSchemaName() in Liquibase?
What is the use of both the methods in Liquibase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default schema is the schema managed by Liquibase - i.e. when you create a table, it will be created the the default schema. The Liquibase schema name is where the Liquibase control tables (`DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK`) are kept.